# comfortable Mexican sofa removes classes from divs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I'm trying to get some parts of my site under a cms with comfortable mexican sofa.

I created the site and made it use my application.html layout. Then I tried to add a page and copy pasted my current index page source into the html editor. But when the html was pasted into the editor all the classes and id's were removed. Only html tags and texts were left. I tried to manually add a class to a div but after pressing "update page" it just disappeared. I can see the manually added class if I browse the revision history, but it doesn't show in the editor nor it is applied into the html rendered into the browser when previewing the page.

Stripping the class and id attributes from the elements works so well that it must be a planned feature. But how to turn that feature off?

I'm on rails 4.1.4

Comment: Hmm.. I created a simple test layout from Comfy's example and when I create a page with that layout the classes and id's are not stripped away. Why couldn't I add classes and id's to the pages whose layout is my application layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was `{{ cms:page:content:rich_text }}` in the layout content on Comfy's side. When I changed that into `{{ cms:page:content }}` the classes and id's started to stay in the pages.